# Write String and integer in bytes in binary file, reading them both and overwriting integer in java

Tags: java, file, inputstream, outputstream, randomaccessfile

I want to write a program in java and I want to use binary file to save data. This program will use Two types of data - date, which will be a String and amount of money which will be double. I want to:

- save them in the same file (at first go I want to get current date and set amount to 0.00)
- read both of them separately (and put their values into variables)
- have ability to overwrite but only double amount (I want date to stay the same)
- after I will overwrite amount I want to read it again (but this time only double)

I have attempted to create file, write to it and read it (I am checking is file existing in other methods, so don't worry about that) and I have encountered multiple problems.

1. Programs writes double as bytes, but string as text (while I wanted
   them to be binary).
2. I either write or read incorrect double value.
3. It doesn't read String correctly.
4. I was trying to look for a solution in java documentation and here on StackOverflow and I have found one topic saying that I should use RandoAccessFile if I want to overwrite part of binary file. But I am still very inexperienced and I can't find out how to use it in actual code. I don't know how to get legth of each value in binary and then have to set accesspoint correclty.
5. I have used deprecated method, and my compiler still cross it out. I might be wrong but In the future I want to convert this java application to android, so I thought it's okay to use as much metchods from older editions of java since android do not accept newest ones (at least this is what I have been told. If I am wrong please correct me).

I am still very inexperienced. I was looking for a solution for a while but I just can't find it. So I would like to seek your wisdom and ask you for help. Thank you!

```
static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
static Date date = new Date();
try{
        final Formatter filecreation = new Formatter("sData.bin");
        filecreation.close();

        DataOutputStream datafill = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("sData.bin"));
        datafill.writeChars(dateFormat.format(date));
        datafill.writeDouble(0.00);

        //Debug
        System.out.println("File created");

    }
    catch(Exception a) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File has not been created","Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
static public void readfile () {
    String finaldate = "";
    Double amount = 0.00;
    try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("sData.bin"));

        finaldate = in.readLine();

        while(in.available() > 0) {

            amount = in.readDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("You have spend" + amount);
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
```

**Edit: Thanks for your info, I finally managed to write and read everything correctly. But still I did not managed to overwrite double value in binary file. Now it looks like this and always immidiately after I attempt to overwrite double it throws exception**

```
String finaldate = "";
    Double amount = 0.00;
    try {

        // create a new RandomAccessFile with filename test
        RandomAccessFile sDataRAF = new RandomAccessFile("sData.bin", "rws");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("sData.bin"));

        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            finaldate += in.readChar();
        }

        System.out.println(finaldate.length());

        System.out.println(finaldate);
        amount = in.readDouble();
        System.out.println(amount);


        //overwrite double
        sDataRAF.seek(10);
        sDataRAF.writeDouble(30.0);

        amount = in.readDouble();
        System.out.println(amount);

                    in.close();
        sDataRAF.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
```

Comment: You are writing the string with `writeChars` and reading it with `readLine`.

Comment: And then if I will read it with readLine, how can I make it ignore this double value which will be in the same file and line exackly after String?

Comment: since you use a fixed size format for the date, you know that the string for this date is 10 chars long, so you can skip these bytes: try to use skipBytes(10) instead of readLine()